# 'Restclient' does not contain a 'BaseUrl' Error

Tags: asp.net-core

I am working on Asp.net core project. trying to send mail using mailgun. used mailgun C# code given in https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#sending-via-api
But getting an error "RestClient" does not contain a "BaseUrl" error.

Comment: Maybe you are using [RestClient](https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/RestClient.Net) and it doesn't have a BaseUrl property? I do see a BaseUri in the docs for RestClient examples.

Comment: Show the code where you send the Api request and your registration of an HttpClient.

Comment: client.BaseUrl = new Uri("https://api.mailgun.net/v3"); // In this line getting error

Comment: public static RestResponse SendSimpleMessage()  {
        RestClient client = new RestClient();
        client.BaseUrl = new Uri("https://api.mailgun.net/v3");
        client.Authenticator =
            new HttpBasicAuthenticator("api",
                                        "YOUR_API_KEY");
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
        request.AddParameter("domain", "YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME", ParameterType.UrlSegment);    
        return client.Execute(request);    }} @neil W

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Add Options before BaseUrl: client.Options.BaseUrl = new Uri("api.mailgun.net/v3")

Answer (score 4):

Since version 107+, RestSharp moved certain properties which cause 'Cannot resolve symbol '.BaseUrl' for example when accessing this. See a list here: https://restsharp.dev/v107/#reference

To access `BaseUrl` property of your `RestClient` you can do the following:

```
var client = new RestClient("yourBaseUrl", options);
var baseUrl = client.Options.BaseUrl;
```

Answer (score 1):

I saw your Comment Code, I think You have to Change this to get the Output.

```
    var client = new RestClient();
    client.BaseUrl = "https://api.mailgun.net/v3";
    client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("api", "YOUR_API_KEY");

    var request = new RestRequest();
    request.Resource = "/address/validate";
    request.AddParameter("address", "address@domain.com");
    //Change Resource and AddParameter as per need

    var response = client.Execute(request);
    dynamic content = Json.Decode(response.Content);
```

Answer (score 1):

Drop your version of RestSharp to below version 107 and give it a try.  Ref: https://restsharp.dev/v107/#restsharp-v107

Answer (score 0):

You just have to make sure that when making an actual call, the url has a value.
You can a.) assign a value to the base url and use a relative path in your call or b.) leave the base url empty and provide an absolute path in the call, they are both OK.
Make sure that when you make the call, the url is set either way.

Answer (score -1):

```
var client = new RestClient(new Uri("yourbaseurl"));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).